# Reference Python module docstring from within a class

Tags: python, docstring

Consider the following code:

```
"""Module documentation."""
import argparse

class HandleArgs()
    """Class documentation"""
    def __call__()
        """Method documentation"""
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description= __doc__)
```

This code will try to use the docstring for the method, not the module. How do I access the module docstring from within a method within the class?

Comment: That's not true. The code will use the module docstring. If you want to use the class docstring, then `self.__doc__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement is not correct. Your code will use the module docstring. If you want to use the class docstring, then `self.__doc__`

See below for completed example.

```
"""Module documentation."""
import argparse

class HandleArgs:
    """Class documentation"""
    def __call__(self):
        """Method documentation"""
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
        print(parser)

ha = HandleArgs()
ha()
```

Output

> ArgumentParser(prog='docs.py', usage=None, description='Module documentation.', formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)

While

```
"""Module documentation."""
import argparse

class HandleArgs:
    """Class documentation"""
    def __call__(self):
        """Method documentation"""
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
        print(parser)

ha = HandleArgs()
ha()
```

Output:

> ArgumentParser(prog='docs.py', usage=None, description='Class documentation', formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
> pc@dev:~/projects/stackoverflow$